# rails deployment script to deploy on local machine (without ssh)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

Our deployment process is that we copy the code from usb to the deployment machine. So the production machine does not have access to git codebase, and we only need to do a deployment to the local machine. We need to automate this deployment process.

Can we adapt capistrano for this need? A deploy strategy of :copy can be used, but we wont need to ssh to the machine, since we will be executing the cap script for deployment to the same machine. So how to change the cap deploy configuration to achieve deployment on the same machine without using ssh?

If capistrano cannot be used for scenarios where no ssh to the remote machine is needed, what is the other option to automate the deployment process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i googled for "cap deploy on localhost" and found this link among others: [develop and deploy on the same box with capistrano](http://rcrowley.org/2007/07/22/develop-and-deploy-on-the-same-box-with-capistrano.html) but this does not completely work, at least with my deployment, so i did the following:
create `vendor/plugins/cap_ext/recipes/my_copy.rb` with the line:

```
$:.unshift File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'my_copy')
```

and then `vendor/plugins/cap_extensions/recipes/my_copy/capistrano/recipes/deploy/strategy/my_copy.rb`
and copied the `copy.rb` file there, changed the class definition to:

```
class MyCopy < Copy
end
```

and then made the changes there that i needed.